# Why does this cypher query take time?

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

```
START n = node(38292)
MATCH  n - [rel_0?:CAN_READ] -> node_0,
n - [rel_1?:CAN_READ] -> node_1,
n - [rel_2?:CAN_READ] -> node_2,
n - [rel_3?:CAN_WRITE] -> node_3,
n - [rel_4?:CAN_WRITE] -> node_4,
n - [rel_5?:CAN_WRITE] -> node_5,
n - [rel_6?:MODULE_TAG] -> node_6,
n - [rel_7?:DUMMY_EDGE] -> node_7,
n - [rel_8?:ANOTHER_DUMMY_EDGE] -> node_8,
n - [rel_9?:IN_QUEUE] -> node_9,
n <- [rel_10?:MODULE_PARENT] - node_10,
n <- [rel_11?:TO_MODULE] - node_11,
n <- [rel_12?:BUILT] - node_12,
n <- [rel_13?:ACCESS_TO] - node_13,
n <- [rel_14?:ACCESS_TO] - node_14
SET n.relationships = '[[CAN_READ, '+COALESCE(ID(node_0), '-1')+', {}] [CAN_READ, '+COALESCE(ID(node_1), '-1')+', {}] [CAN_READ, '+COALESCE(ID(node_2), '-1')+', {}] [CAN_WRITE, '+COALESCE(ID(node_3), '-1')+', {}] [CAN_WRITE, '+COALESCE(ID(node_4), '-1')+', {}] [CAN_WRITE, '+COALESCE(ID(node_5), '-1')+', {}] [MODULE_TAG, '+COALESCE(ID(node_6), '-1')+', {title:'+COALESCE(STR(rel_6.title), "''") +' }] [DUMMY_EDGE, '+COALESCE(ID(node_7), '-1')+', {p1:'+COALESCE(STR(rel_7.p1), "''") +'  p2:'+COALESCE(STR(rel_7.p2), "''") +' }] [ANOTHER_DUMMY_EDGE, '+COALESCE(ID(node_8), '-1')+', {p3:'+COALESCE(STR(rel_8.p3), "''") +'  p4:'+COALESCE(STR(rel_8.p4), "''") +' }] [IN_QUEUE, '+COALESCE(ID(node_9), '-1')+', {id:'+COALESCE(STR(rel_9.id), "''") +'  date_added:'+COALESCE(STR(rel_9.date_added), "''") +'  date_viewed:'+COALESCE(STR(rel_9.date_viewed), "''") +'  display_order:'+COALESCE(STR(rel_9.display_order), "''") +' }] [MODULE_PARENT, '+COALESCE(ID(node_10), '-1')+', {display_order:'+COALESCE(STR(rel_10.display_order), "''") +' }] [TO_MODULE, '+COALESCE(ID(node_11), '-1')+', {}] [BUILT, '+COALESCE(ID(node_12), '-1')+', {}] [ACCESS_TO, '+COALESCE(ID(node_13), '-1')+', {}] [ACCESS_TO, '+COALESCE(ID(node_14), '-1')+', {}]]'
```

Explanation:

This query starts from a single node, goes through its relationships and stores the id of the other end as a property of this node. 
For example, if these properties exist among nodes with ids `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`,

```
1-[:A]->2
1-[:B]->3
1-[:C]->4
```

Then `1.relationships` will be set to `[[A, 2], [B, 3], [C, 4]]`

Its a pretty simple query structurally, but the first time, it takes ~8 secs, and subsequently, its fast (~100ms)

Comment: How much data are you touching? This might be a caching issue, where the first time your data needs to be read fully from disk. make sure you adjust your cache settings.